# sorting not correct

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a sorting (ORDER BY) problem with my query which I can't figure out
It is returning sorted values as below, even with the option ORDER BY active at the right column.

```
SUPPLIER(t.naam) - ORDER DATE (r.datum) - ARTICLE
```

and I need

```
ORDER DATE (r.datum) - SUPPLIER(t.naam) - ARTICLE



$towhere = '';
if ($_SESSION['user']['type'] == 'to') {
    $towhere .= ' and p.relaties_code_0 ="' . (string)$_SESSION['user']['code'] . '"';
}
if (isset($_SESSION['jetnet']) && $_SESSION['jetnet']) {
    $towhere .= ' and p.relaties_code_0 in (' . $jetnet_touroperators . ')';
}

$query = 'SELECT p.id
          ,p.relaties_code
        ,r.datum      
          ,t.naam as touroperator
          ,p.taalcodes_taalcode as taal
          ,p.tmsritd_id
          ,p.aantal
          ,p.artikel_id
         ,p.memoverzending
          ,p.omschr
          ,p.tmsinvoicecode_code as tmsinvoicecode,
          po.impref01 AS ponummer
      FROM tmspickd (NOLOCK) p join tmsbstreld (NOLOCK) po on po.id=p.tmsbstreld_id join relaties (NOLOCK) t on p.relaties_code_0=t.code join tmsritd (NOLOCK) rd on p.tmsritd_id=rd.id join tmsrit (NOLOCK) r on rd.tmsrit_id=r.id where p.relaties_code=\'' . (string)$_SESSION['user']['bestelcode'] . '\' ' . $towhere . ' order by r.datum desc, p.relaties_code_0, p.artikel_id';

$rows = S::getAll($query, array());

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    //Y-m-d
    $row['datum'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['datum']));
    $row['omschr'] = htmlentities($row['omschr']);

    //controleer als ponummer numeriek is
    if (!is_numeric(substr($row['ponummer'], 0, 5))) {
        $row['ponummer'] = "";
    }

    $tplvars['delivered'][] = $row;
```

Any help anybody? Thanks!

The information from my client is confidential, so I can't put real sample data here. So I made it generic, but it's very simple to understand.
clients can order different products online, from different suppliers
in the order history view, i need to show the first scheduled delivery date descending
now it's sorting on supplier name and mixing up the date's. so clients call false for missing orders

We are using a Windows CRM application with MSSQL database with an PHP online application for clients to order products.

Sample data:

```
SCHEDULED DELIVERY DATE   SUPPLIER              ARTICLE
2015-02-03                sup1                   product A
2015-02-03                sup2                   product D
2015-02-01                sup1                   product A
2015-02-14                sup3                   product X
2015-02-15                sup3                   product Y
2015-02-16                sup4                   product Z
2015-02-01                sup1                   product A
```

Comment: Give us some sample data, both with current order and wanted order!

Comment: Edit your question and add that in - in a readable format too

Comment: Thanks, but please, edit your question instead, and format it so we can read it without problems!

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Well so far your sample data is matching your order by. What are you expecting/wanting to get?

Comment: no it is not maching completely, sorry I forgot some lines

Now it's sorting on supplier, so data is coming out on sup1, sup2, sup3, sup4
I want it to come out as date descending. The newest/most recent dates first

Comment: I have updated the question with also the php code. I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Is that sample data wanted output, or what you get? I don't get this, there

Comment: It's output what I get
You can see the delivery date's are not descending order; they are mixed up
I want all of them them to be DESC

Comment: Nobody who can help me with this?